# Should I re-use a single HTML::SimpleLinkExtor object for memory efficiency?

Tags: perl, memory, memory-efficient

So this may seem like a silly question, but I'm building an application where memory is a very limited resource so I need to be as cautious about memory usage as I can. So my question is, which of the following is more memory efficient?

```
while(<LINKS_FILE>) {
    my $extor = HTML::SimpleLinkExtor->new($resp->base); #$resp from above somewhere
    $extor->parse($_);
    my @links = $extor->links;
    for my $link (@links) { print "$link\n" }
}
```

or

```
my $extor = HTML::SimpleLinkExtor->new($resp->base); #$resp from above somewhere
while(<LINKS_FILE>) {
    $extor->parse($_);
    my @links = $extor->links;
    for my $link (@links) { print "$link\n" }
    $extor->clear_links;
}
```

So in the first it creates a new HTML::SimleLinkExtor object every time, whereas in the second it just kind of resets the same one for use again. So it seems to me like the second one would be more memory efficient, but to be honest I don't really know how good perl is about releasing memory back to the os, or if it's gonna hold on to the memory for some of the HTML::SimpleLinkExtor objects even after they're out of scope. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just test it, try to run it with couple of thousands of HTML's and see the memory consumption of each, probably try use 'Benchmark' module as well while doing so.

Comment: Perl dosent release memory back to the OS.... but memory it released will be reused by perl in case needed, at least from what I know

Comment: Is `LINKS_FILE` the HTML document you are parsing? My gut tells me you'll be better off not sending bits and pieces to the `SimpleLinkExtor` object. I don't know the internals of `HTML::SimpleLinkExtor`, but you'd probably be better off handing over the stream to the parser.

Answer (score 1):

I am not inclined to spend time profiling, but if I were in your situation, I would try [HTML::LinkExtor](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML%3a%3aLinkExtor) first. If you provide a callback, it will not save the links it finds internally, reducing the footprint of your application. You can then decide whether to store the links, or maybe write to an external file, to keep memory use to a minimum:

```
use HTML::LinkExtor;
my $parser = HTML::LinkExtor->new(sub {
     my($tag, %links) = @_;
     print "$tag @{[%links]}\n";
});

$parser->parse_file("index.html");
```